# Can static combinable<T> be used as a placeholder to thread_local?

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-studio-2010, thread-local

C++0x adds a new storage specifier [`thread_local`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B0x#Thread-local_storage) which is not yet implemented in VS10.

However the Parallel Programming Library defines a [`Concurrency::combinable` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492850.aspx) which has a `local()` function which *Returns a reference to the thread-private sub-computation*.

Are there semantics for `thread_local` that can't be (easily) covered by having a `static` variable of type `combinable<T>`?

If not why was `thread_local` added to the core language if it can be implemented in a library?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why C++ added *class* objects whether it could be implemented by a library like something that *GObject* does in C? Because C++ wants *class* objects to be known at **compile-time**, this is more efficient. Therefore C++ class initialization/uninitialization is exception-safe ([RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAII)).

Some features are more major and needed more implementation to be made. *thread_local* is a *storage class specifier*, so it can be known at **compile-time** and compiler can do much more optimization.

Also in http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2659.htm have said:

> Thread Variable Dynamic Initialization
>
> At present, **all implementations** of thread-local storage do **not support** dynamic initalization (and presumably non-trivial destructors). There was mild consensus at the Mont Treblant meeting to support dynamic initialization of function-local, thread-local variables. The intialization of such variables is already guarded and synchronous, so new technology is not required. On the other hand, the implementation for dynamic initialization of namespace-scope variables is **much more difficult**, and **may require additional linker and operating system support**.

Why `thread_local` have been introduced as a new language keyword? It seems that the reason could be *Thread Variable Dynamic Initialization*.